# Angular ng probe: get reference to token to use with injector

Tags: angular, debugging, import, probe

I am trying to do something like this in browser console:

```
ng.probe($('app-root')).injector.get(AuthenticationService)
```

This does not work, since `AuthenticationService` token is not discovered.In my code, I would have written `import { AuthenticationService } from '@lib';` How can I get the service from injector in console?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm trying to do the same thing.